# Integer reverse output (fixing the number with 0)

Tags: java

I am trying to reverse the output of my code and it's working, the problem is when I input 12345678910 the "10" is not displayed.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test3{
     public static void main(String args[]) {
     Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
     int num=0,rev=0,rev1=0,limit=0,num1=0;  
     System.out.print("Enter A Number: ");
     limit=in.nextInt();

        for (int i=0;i<limit;i++){
           num=in.nextInt();

             while (num >0) {
                 rev = rev*10 + num % 10;
                    num /= 10;
              }
          }
     num1=rev;
         while(num1>0){
           rev1 = rev1 * 10 + num1 %10;
               num1 /=10;

   }
       System.out.println(rev1);
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "10 is not displayed"? The reverse of `12345678910` is `01987654321`, but since numbers don't explicitly store leading zeroes, the *numeric value* is `1987654321`. If you want leading zeroes to be retained, you need to do this using strings, not numeric types.

Comment: *"when i input 12345678910 the "10" is not display"* That is true, because output is **`InputMismatchException: For input string: "12345678910"`**, since the entered number exceeds the value range of an `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 12345678910 the "10" is not display

because this while loop `while (num >0)` is running twice for `10`, as a result `rev` is overflowing and holding negative value (`-539222978`) since `int` can not hold more than `2^32-1` it wraps around to negative value (`-539222978`) . what is why you got `revl` initial value `0` got printed,

So try to use `StringBuilder`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
public class Test3{
     public static void main(String args[]) {
     Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     String numStr; 
     System.out.print("Enter A Number: ");
     int limit=in.nextInt();
        for (int i=0;i<limit;i++){
           numStr=in.next();
           sb.append(numStr);
          }
        System.out.println(sb.reverse().toString());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit complicated:

```
public static String ReturnString()
{
    long input = 12345678910L;
    String inputAsString = Long.toString(input);
    String rev = "";
    for (int temp = inputAsString.length() - 1; temp > -1; temp--)
    {
        rev += inputAsString.charAt(temp);
    }

return rev;

}
```

Comment: why "10" is not displayed?

Comment: rev = rev*10 + num % 10; (this line wont work for 0)..rev is 0 for 0..in the next iteration it will try to add the second last digit (1) to 0: which returns 1.

Comment: your code will work fine for 1234567891 even if you change to: long num = 1234578910L;